Pausing execution based on DateTime C# .NET
The current situation:
I have an order that is started in the client side and that should run continiously in the backend doing tasks in that order until the time is not within 09:00 - 17:00 (The working time). It should not run on weekends as well. When it's not working time the execution of tasks should stop until next working itme. I am currently implementing this functionality kind of succesfully with Thread.Sleep(). I know this solution is frowned upon, so I am open to other solutions.
So the current behavior of the program:

Client starts order
It checks the time, it's within 9-17 and not the weekend.
It starts executing tasks until 17 and then succesfully stops.
A utility function calculates how long the thread should sleep in milliseconds until the execution of task should start again.
I check the next day (It's running on a hosted Azure App Service) and it has succesfully sent the message to frontend at the correct time 09:00 that execution of tasks will presume.
However the execution of tasks is not happening, when I know that there exists remaining tasks on that order object.

[HttpPost ("/StartWorkFromClientSide")]
public async Task < IActionResult > StartWork (string orderID)
{
    var order = Orders.find (orderID);
    
    while (!order.IsCompleted)
    {

        for (task in order.tasks) {

        //this DateTime var should be recalculated 
        //when continue in condition block executes and then execute current task 
    DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;

    if (currentDateTime is weekend || time is not within 0900:1700)
    {

            var sleepTime = calculateSleepTime (currentDateTime);
        Thread.Sleep (sleepTime);
        //when done sleeping (potentially in 1-3 days), 
                //start tasks again and send msg to frontend
            await clients.hub.all.sendMessage (someMessage);

        //since continue skips current loop item remove and append so its done later, 
        //the order of the tasks is not important:
        order.tasks.remove (task);
        order.tasks.append (task);
        continue;

    }

    execute (task);

    } //end of for loop


}


(Pseudo-ish code of my actual implementation ^)

Ok, first of all: The highest priority must be to get rid of that Thread.Sleep. If the overall requirement is to have a recurring task that shall run in a specific schedule, then you should really consider using a Scheduling Framework or Service.

There's also a tight loop in case it's out of schedule ... >> depending on your cloud payment tier you could cause a lot of money go down the drain !! <<

When it's not working in that case Thread.Sleep is also not working. There are a lot of scheduling libraries like Coravel, Hangfire, Quartz.NET and none of them uses Thread.Sleep, delays or timers for every job. No in-memory object can survive the termination of a process or a restart. All libraries store tasks and schedules in some form of permanent storage and periodically check, eg every 1 second or minute, to see if they have something to run, or to retry jobs that had to run while the scheduler was down

BUT if you're on a cloud service you pay for every second your app is running. In most cases it would be cheaper to use Azure's own scheduling services that keeping your site up all the time. sent the message to frontend you can create a job that notifies your application to send a message to the front end. Or, if you use Azure SignalR, you can send the message to the same SignalR hub used by the site

Cloud services put VMs or services that have no traffic to sleep too, until a request is received. If your site has no traffic off hours, it could easily be turned off until the first user logs in the next day.

But execution happens after the Sleep Period (The message that is sent to clientside) so that proves that the thread is not terminated and could be used to further execute tasks? I could schedule the tasks but the interval cannot be predetermined since the time it takes to perform these tasks is unknown.

Okay, so the problem may be that the order object does not exist in memory after the sleep duration? So maybe do a re-fetch from db of this object after the sleep period?

@OleAskeland
The scheduler will execute the tasks, at a fix point in time, that you can define.
If your tasks need to stop executing when a certain time is reached, that is a different problem, but a task started within the valid defined timespace will finish executing, provided the task isn't infinite.
You will not need to have a sleep period, let's say you tell your system to run every 3 minutes, but that task takes an hour, depending on your "valid time" it will simply create a task every three minutes, that finishes execution 1 hour later. There is no need to "sleep"

if you do not want parallel running tasks,then I recommend setting up a Timer, then setting the timer interval to nothing, and then stopping the timer, as it's event, create a try, with a finally that starts the timer. You will not sleep, and the tasks cannot run in parallel and will run as much as possible, provided the timer is defined to run in the "correct time".
